# Value must match the regular expression ^[^A-Z]+$ - Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, package.json

I created a new project and chose the template Angular 2 ASP.Net Core in VS 2015 and when I opened the package.json I started seeing this warning.How do I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The expresssion `^[^A-Z]+$` means from the beginning of the string all the way to the end there must be at least one character, and the characters may not be upper case letters. You have this value:

```
Angular2Spa
```

To comply with the expression, try this:

```
angular2spa
```

Given the text of the error message, that there is also a 214 character limit, I'm surprised they don't use this expression instead:

```
^[^A-Z]{1,214}$
```

Answer (score 2):

The validations are defined in JSON schema.

By default, the schema used is from http://json.schemastore.org/package .
The validation specified there states that package names must not include capital letters, which is why it is complaining:

```
...
"name": {
    "description": "The name of the package.",
    "type": "string",
    "maxLength": 214,
    "minLength": 1,
    "pattern": "^[^A-Z]+$"
},
...
```

For instructions how to change your JSON schema see [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json#_json-schemas-settings).

Answer (score 0):

Changed the name to smaller case and the warning went away.

[image]